# How do you override a single Ivy setting in SBT?

Tags: sbt, ivy

I'm wrestling with some Ivy issues in SBT and I'm looking for a way to override one single Ivy setting, but leave everything else exactly as it is. Specifically, I'd like to change the `httpRequestMethod` value.

The closest solution I have found is to add `externalIvySettings()` to build.sbt, then create an ivysettings.xml file that has only that one setting in it, but when I do that, it is apparently womping out other settings, because I can no longer download anything.

So does anyone know how to override the `httpRequestMethod` property without changing anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Warning: Experimental

Not sure if this would work, but `sbt` does expose its internal Ivy instance via `ivySbt` key. So you *might* be able to do this:

```scala
ivySbt := {
  import org.apache.ivy.Ivy
  import org.apache.ivy.util.url.{URLHandlerRegistry, URLHandler}
  val old = ivySbt.value
  val s = streams.value
  old.withIvy(s.log) { ivy: Ivy =>
    URLHandlerRegistry.getHttp().setRequestMethod(URLHandler.REQUEST_METHOD_GET)
    old
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick, but it gave me something to start tinkering with at least :). Thanks.